# How to create a json API for my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'd like to create a json API that I can access publicly for my custom post type without help of any external plugins in WordPress.

Can anyone shed some light on it please?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems a bit vague, there a lot of steps creating an API, but I'll try to resume:

1. Create an interaction page (You can use the wp-ajax or a page template)
2. Code the function which will read parameters and execute the code
3. Output only the result to browser. You can output json with a code line like:

`echo json_encode( $result );`

Comment: Yes. I do agree it's kind of vague and too broad to answer. I was looking for the approach this can be achieved. Thank You for the answer it'll surely help. However I have one last question perhaps. How can I access and pull the data from this in the front end?

Comment: Once you have done all the back-end api process, just access the URL of your API with a file_get_contents and use the json_decode. Like this:

`$data = file_get_contents("http://mywebsite.com/api/?parameter=1&parameter=2");
echo json_decode($data);`

Comment: Yeah. I tried. file_get_contents(), wp_remote_get(), curl none of them working.

Comment: returning NULL in every cases

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you
[WPApi](http://v2.wp-api.org)

Comment: Op asked for no plugins.

Comment: @DanGayle in next Wordpress release it is gonna be a part of core :)

Comment: @vol4ijman. I take it back then :)

Comment: @DanGayle Yeah. In 4.4 it'll be a core feature I saw.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a json endpoint with WordPress's rewrite rule API.

Here's how:

```
// Add custom rewrite rule

function test_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%movies%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'movie-api/([^&]+)/?', 'index.php?movies=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'test_rewrite_rule' );

// outputting the data

function test_movie_endpoint_data() {

    global $wp_query;

    $movie_tag = $wp_query->get( 'movies' );

    if ( ! $movie_tag ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $movie_tag == 'all' ) {
        $movie_tag = false;
    }

    $movie_data = array();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'movies',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'moxie_tag'    => esc_attr( $movie_tag ),
    );

    $movie_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) :       
    $movie_query->the_post();

    $movie_data[] = array(
        'id'    => get_the_id(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'poster_url' => esc_url( test_get_meta('poster_url') ),
        'rating' => test_get_meta('rating'), 
        'year' => test_get_meta('year'),
        'short_description' => test_get_meta('description'),
    );
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endif;

    wp_send_json( $movie_data );

} 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test_movie_endpoint_data' );
```

But while I try to pull the json data with wordpress's wp_remote_get(), curl or file_get_contents() it's returning NULL.

Any idea what's the best way to get those information on the front end form the end point?